# Concatenate or filter several columns data.table

Tags: r, data.table

My data.frame has several columns which I would like to filter with the same `grepl`.

Instead of

```
dt[!grepl(x=colA, pattern='goaway'),]
dt[!grepl(x=colB, pattern='goaway'),]
dt[!grepl(x=colC, pattern='goaway'),]
dt[!grepl(x=colD, pattern='goaway'),]
etc
```

I would like to either do something like

```
filterCols <- c('colA', 'colB', 'colC','colD')
dt[!grepl(x=paste0(get(filterCols), collapse=""), pattern="goaway"),]
```

Afterwords I would like to be smarter than this:

```
db[colA == ""]$colA <- NA
db[colB == ""]$colB <- NA
db[colC == ""]$colC <- NA

db[, colA := zoo::na.locf(colA),]
db[, colB := zoo::na.locf(colB),]
db[, colC := zoo::na.locf(colC),]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#how-can-i-avoid-writing-a-really-long-j-expression-youve-said-that-i-should-use-the-column-names-but-ive-got-a-lot-of-columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `.SDcols` to work on selected columns. So something like this :

```
library(data.table)
dt[, Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, grepl, pattern = 'goaway')), .SDcols = filterCols]
```

and for the second part similarly,

```
db[, (filterCols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) 
     zoo::na.locf(replace(x, x == "", NA))), .SDcols = filterCols]
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak - This is simply excellent! I have never used reduce before. Looking through the documentation I would not have guessed that I could use a pipe like a binary function.